# Get grouped and counted entries from the last 7 days in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

Im currently stuck in a little problem.
I do want to receive a result of dates, grouped by the day, and counted by the day.

```
Day 2021-08-06 | count 12
Day 2021-08-05 | count 130 
Day 2021-08-04 | count 0 
Day 2021-08-03 | count 10 
Day 2021-08-02 | count 80 
Day 2021-08-01 | count 35 
Day 2021-07-31 | count 54
```

Any ideas on how to solve that one?

My approach was something like:

```
public function getEntries()
{
    $this->where('created_at','>=',Carbon::now()->subDays(7))->get();
}
```

Would be very glad for help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering this method is inside your Model, you can use:

```php
public function getEntries()
{
    return DB::table($this->getTable())
        ->selectRaw('count(*) as count, DATE(created_at) day')
        ->groupBy('day')
        ->where('created_at', ">", DB::raw('DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 7 Month)'))
        ->get();
}
```

**Note:** This is tested on MySQL and was working fine, not tested on other databases.